# Setting 2 label in header programatically - not label seen

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to set 2 labels, one under other with different font size in the header. The function is called like this:

```
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = self.setHeader()
```

And code responsible for generating label is :

```
private func setHeader(agentName: String = "", isTyping: Bool = false) -> UIView {
    let headerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = self.title
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        return label
    }()

    let subheaderLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        return label
    }()

    let headerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
                ])



        return view
    }()



    if (!agentName.isEmpty) {
        if (isTyping) {
            subheaderLabel.text = agentName + " is typing ..."
        } else {
            subheaderLabel.text = agentName
        }
        headerView.addSubview(subheaderLabel)
    }

    return headerView
}
```

When I running IOS app there is nothing shown in the header. What is a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the frame for the headerView. So in the initialization code for the `headerView`, use initializer with `frame`:

```
let headerView: UIView = {
    // initialize the view with frame
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 35))
    // you want to call this on the headerLabel, not on view
    headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(headerLabel)
    view.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
            ])
        return view
    }()
```

Moreover, I believe `headerLabel` you want to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on `headerLabel` rather than on `headerView` (`headerView` is positioned through frame and not Autolayout).

Also, notice that you add `subheaderLabel` to the view, but you never position it, don't forget about it either (although this should cause only `subheaderLabel` not to be rendered properly).

Comment: Hi apply changes but see only ... not 2 label .

Comment: use bigger frame, it's probably minimized label.. and remember to set up autolayout for the second label

Comment: @MarceliJanowski if the answer was helpful, please accept it